# Are the estimates of the coefficients b0, b1 in the regression model y = b0 + b1x + ε random variables or unknown parameters?

Tags: statistics, regression

In class we have mentioned both terms in regard to the coefficients along with other terminology and I'm totally confused about which one is true

Comment: When you assume $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \varepsilon,$ you are assuming that $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are some parameters non-random and fixed, but unknown. You create _estimates_ $\hat \beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$ which are functions of the observed data. As the data is assumed random, so are the estimates.

Comment: For MathJAX, type underscores to make subscripts. Typing ```$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i$$``` will render the equation:$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i$$

Comment: Thank you, Joe. That's what my professor meant but you said it more clearly.

Comment: @WilliamM. is the one who clearly explained that the parameters are taken to be unknown constants, but the estimators are statistics (functions of random samples), and hence are random variables.  I only gave a tip on MathJAX.